# javascript work on windows but don't work on linux

Tags: javascript, php, linux

This javascript dropdown list auto complete work on windows local server in PHP aplication, but when i try this funcionality when aplication is on linux server nothing happen. Maybe i should change live method into on? But how?

This is javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$(".search_keyword").keyup(function() 
{ 
    var search_keyword_value = $(this).val();
    var dataString = 'search_keyword='+ search_keyword_value;
    if(search_keyword_value!='')
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "search.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html)
                {
                    $("#result").html(html).show();
                }
        });
    }
    return false;    
});

$("#result").on("click",function(e){
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    var $name = $clicked.find('.country_name').html();  
    var decoded = $("<div/>").html($name).text();
    $('#search_keyword_id').val(decoded);
});

$(document).o("click", function(e) { 
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    if (! $clicked.hasClass("search_keyword")){
        $("#result").fadeOut(); 
    }
});

$('#search_keyword_id').click(function(){
    $("#result").fadeIn();
});
});
</script>
```

And this is search.php

```
 include('db.php');
    if(isset($_POST['search_keyword']))
    {
        $search_keyword = $polaczenie->real_escape_string($_POST['search_keyword']);
        $sqlCountries="SELECT name FROM shop WHERE name LIKE '%$search_keyword%'";
        $resCountries=$polaczenie->query($sqlCountries);

        if($resCountries === false) {
            trigger_error('Error: ' . $polaczenie->error, E_USER_ERROR);
        }else{
            $rows_returned = $resCountries->num_rows;
        }

    $bold_search_keyword = '<strong>'.$search_keyword.'</strong>';
    if($rows_returned > 0){
            while($rowCountries = $resCountries->fetch_assoc()) 
            {       
                echo '<div class="show" align="left"><span class="country_name">'.str_ireplace($search_keyword,$bold_search_keyword,$rowCountries['nazwa']).'</span></div>';    
            }
        }else{
            echo '<div class="show" align="left">Brak</div>';   
        }
    }
```

Comment: The server OS has nothing to do with how JavaScript works when it gets to the client browser. Have you verified that your server configuration is actually serving that JavaScript file properly? Are there errors in the browser console?

Comment: As @Pointy said, the browsers engine runs the JavaScript, and the serve-type of the content won't matter. Check that both JS serves are identical then do some debugging in the browser development tools, http://getfirebug.com/

Comment: I have not seen any errors. I think server configuration is fine beacuse i have other javascript which take date (datepicker) and working properly.

Comment: I'm not shure whether I will have the opportunity to see if there are any errors (on linux) because when I type a letter in the input he does not react at all (no shows dropdown list with suggestion)

Comment: Have you checked the **browser console** for errors? Have you verified that the HTTP request to load the script is actually completing correctly?

Comment: [![firebug.jpg](https://s23.postimg.org/adflffpxn/firebug.jpg)](https://postimg.org/image/4chwid3bb/)  there are 500 internal server error for each letter when i write in the input